# Android bubble chat different layout after first user message

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, chat

I am creating "bubble" style messages representation in my chat application's listview adapter. This is the effect that I want to achieve:

[image]

As you can see, second user message should show up in different layout (without picture) if user wrote two or more messages in a row. How I can achieve this? Because seems it's quite complicated. Should I check last message type in adapter (doesn't look so reliable solution)? Or add and later check additional field in my message object? Any example or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use different 9 patches. And a boolean (say `isFirst`).

Comment: Yeah, in the future for sure I will use nine-patches. I know that solution is based probably on simple boolean/booleans. Just I am interested from architectural point of view - where exactly in the code to work with boolean. To see any code example would be great.

Comment: `To see any code example would be great.` For us, as well. In order to be able to help you.

Comment: Anyway, by **wild guesses**: Where you show the picture is a good place to set the boolean to **true**. And after showing that first TextView (you might prefer to set an integer counter, instead of a boolean), set it to **false**.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a Message class like this:

```
class Message {
    public String text;
    public String avatar;
}
```

So, in getView method, you can easy check previous item:

```
ArrayList<Message> mMessages;
...
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){      
    if( convertView == null ){
         if (position > 0 && mMessages.get(position-1).avatar.equal(mMessages.get(position).avatar)){
              // set layout for second message style
              convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_without_avatar, parent, false);
         } else {
              // set layout for the first message style
              convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_with_avatar, parent, false);
         }             
    }
    ...
    return convertView;
}
```

Hope it help!

Comment: yup, u r right, but there is another way similar to yours. check user id with previous item and if same than hide the pic if not than show pic :)